# SQL Command Not Properly Ended Error in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I've checked similar posts as there are a few but could not find a post similar to my query which doesn't contain clauses that typically cause this error. I am very new to SQL (especially Oracle). My query looks right (to me) but obviously it isn't. I checked to see if the ";" at the end was the issue and it wasn't.

Just so you know I gave this considerable time and effort before posting, I tried the following:

- 1. I removed the single quotes
- 2. I removed the brackets (note that the
     names of the fields contain brackets unfortunately)but brackets
     around the field names is common in other SQL flavors.
- 3. I removed
     the single quote and brackets an just separated fields with commas
- 4. I tried just selecting a few fields
- 5. Reviewed several SELECT command examples for Oracle

.

```
SELECT *
  FROM SPECPARAMLIMITS
 WHERE PARAMLISTID IN ('Bacillus cereus'), ('Clostridium perfringens'), 
('Coliform (0.30 MPN/g LOD)'), ('Coliform (3.0 MPN/g LOD)'), ('Coliform (CFU/g)'), 
('Coliform (CFU/mL)'), ('E. coli (0.30 MPN/g LOD)'), ('E. coli (3.0 MPN/g LOD)'), 
('E. coli (CFU/g)'), ('E. coli (CFU/mL)'), ('Enterobacteriaceae'), ('Enterobacteriaceae (per g)'), ('Enterococci/KF Strep'), ('Listeria (per 125 g)'), ('Listeria (per 25 g)'), 
('Mold (10 CFU/g LOD)'), ('Mold (100 CFU/g LOD)'), ('Mold (CFU/mL)'), ('Salmonella (per 100 g)'), ('Salmonella (per 1500 g)'), ('Salmonella (per 25 g)'), ('Salmonella (per 375 g)'), 
('Salmonella (per 750 g)'), ('Salmonella (per lot)(375g)'), ('Standard Plate Count (CFU/g)'), ('Standard Plate Count (CFU/mL)'), ('Staph aureus (10 CFU/g LOD)'), 
('Staph aureus (3 CFU/g LOD)'), ('Staph aureus coag pos (per g)'), 
('Staph Enterotoxin (SET)'), ('Staph. aureus, Coag (pos)'), ('Thermophilic Spore'), 
('Yeast (10 CFU/g LOD)'), ('Yeast (100 CFU/g LOD)'), ('Yeast (CFU/mL)')
```

Comment: An IN statement should have a single set of brackets around a comma-separated list

Answer (score 1):

Just putting this as an answer because the formatting will be easier to read.

```
SELECT *
  FROM SPECPARAMLIMITS
 WHERE PARAMLISTID IN (
           'Bacillus cereus',
           'Clostridium perfringens', 
           'Coliform (0.30 MPN/g LOD)',
           'Coliform (3.0 MPN/g LOD)')
```

et. cetera for the other items.

Comment: Your answer made this very clear. When I removed the brackets around the field names and put brackets at the beginning and end of the WHERE clause, voila, problem solved.  THANK YOU so much to you and NICKW for answering.  The SQL I have mostly been using requires brackets around the field names and no brackets at the start and end of the WHERE clause..